# MissingPluginException for Linux desktop app

Tags: linux, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Just added desktop support to my flutter app, it runs fine in the android emulator, but wont render any element in neither browser nor desktop, just a simple blank page without errors.

[image]

Here is the error I get in console, not sure if that error is really the problem since its from `firebase`.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
Building Linux application...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:40449/v58VaNveMLo=/ws
Syncing files to device Linux...
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:175:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:363:35)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:31:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (package:sqlite_provider_starter/main.dart:9:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: _asynchronous suspension_ means it's waiting for the _async_ and if the firebase stuffs don't work it will stay like that (suspended "forever").

Comment: but its working in the android emulator, its the same code, do I need to change something in the firebase code for it to run on desktop too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For present time `firebase_core` package is supported on Android, IOS, MacOS, and Web. It's not supported yet for `Linux`. Execute your portion of code where you have operations based on that package conditionally according to the host platform.